# Spam in Apple Calendar

Tags: macos, email, calendar

I'm not too familiar with Apple Calendar because I don't use it, but every now & then I get spam entries ending up on it and receive alerts based on them.

My question is how they are getting in there (it's pretty clear that it's happening through email - but I'm not clear on the mechanics), and how do I stop it?

Screenshot below:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: This [site](http://www.techtimes.com/articles/185394/20161110/heres-how-to-stop-icloud-calendar-and-photo-spam-invites.htm) may help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, do not "decline" or "accept" the invitation. It tells the spammer that your account is active.

Next, you need to make a change to your iCloud account.

1. Go to icloud.com
2. Login to your iCloud account
3. Navigate to the Calendar App
4. Click in the settings (gear icon) in the lower left of the screen
5. Select "Preference" from the menu
6. Select the "Advanced" tab
7. Under the "Invitations" section select the "Email to" options

This will not stop the spam, but will forward it to your email, so you can deal with it there and keep it from getting to your calendar.

You can deal with the invitations already on your calendar by moving them to a new calendar and then deleting that calendar.

1. Create a new iCloud calendar (not “On My Mac”).
2. Move the spam event to the new iCloud calendar.
3. Delete the new iCloud calendar.
4. Calendar will now prompt you with “Delete and Don’t Notify” and “Delete and Notify”.
5. Select “Delete and Don’t Notify”.

Answer (score 1):

I have not tested how to prevent it yet, but I have tested the so-called workaround being passed around that recommends moving the invite to a temporary calendar, then deleting that calendar, and answering "Delete and Don't Notify" -- it STILL sends a DECLINE notice.

Folks passing it around and up voting it here and elsewhere did not actually test it out, they just assumed the "Delete and Don't Notify" button did what it promised to do.

Try it with another iCloud user. Your status on their invite will go from NO REPLY to DECLINED shortly after you click "Delete and Don't Reply."

This is repeatable on macOS Sierra 10.12.1 and Calendar 9.0 (2155.8) both are latest versions as of this writing.